# Problem With Creating My first React project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting problem to create my First React native project,
this is what am seeing on the terminal ;Command `yarn add react-native --exact` failed

Comment: nothing else that might be helpful for others that might attempt to help you?

Answer (score 0):

i think you're adding global dependencies wrong,

You should be able to install `react-native-cli` globally with `yarn global add react-native-cli`, not `yarn add global react-native-cli`.

You should be fine with running the following:

```
npm install -g yarn

yarn global add react-native-cli

react-native init ExampleReactNative
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create your first project:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```